# else if condition with 3 checks

Tags: python, if-statement

I am getting 10 result of google search.

My scenario is:

1. if any result(link) out of 10 belongs to wikipedia, consider that result
2. Else consider Google instant result (result which appear on top before links) if exist
3. Else consider description of all 10 link

Here is my code:

```
for contentIndex in self.search_response['links']:
    domain = self.search_response['links'][contentIndex]['domain']
    if "wikipedia.org" in domain:
        google_query = ''
        google_query =  self.search_response['links'][contentIndex]['content']
        print "wiki link"
        break
    elif google_instant:
        google_query = ''
        google_query = google_instant
        print "\n \n Instant result : " + google_instant
        break
    else:
        google_query += self.search_response['links'][contentIndex]['content']
```

But this condition gets crashed. Like if first link is not wiki link and instant result is present then it will not connsider wiki link, but instant result.

Comment: You need to loop on the first condition, since you want to check if *any* of the 10..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: thanks, I need final result in `google_query` var, but it gets appended, so I am confuded

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking out of the loop on the google_instant condition. If this condition is met before you find a wikipedia link, then it will always use the google_instant link. What you actually need to do here is keep iterating through the results, then at the end check if there is a wikipedia or google instant link.

```
search_results = ''
wikipedia_result = None
google_instant_result = None

for contentIndex in self.search_response['links']:
    domain = self.search_response['links'][contentIndex]['domain']
    if "wikipedia.org" in domain:
        wikipedia_rsult =  self.search_response['links'][contentIndex]['content']
        print "wiki link"
    elif google_instant:
        google_instant_result = google_instant
        print "\n \n Instant result : " + google_instant
    else:
        search_results += self.search_response['links'][contentIndex]['content']

google_query = wikipedia_result or google_instant or search_results
```

Comment: it will crash here also I guess. Case: Google instant is not avaialbe and first link is not the wiki link, may be 2nd or 3rd is wiki link. so `search_results` and `wikipedia_rsult` are true now. so what would be the value in `google_query`?

Comment: `wikipedia_result` will be set, so the `google_query` assignment, will use the `wikipedia_result` value. When using or like this, it will use the first 'truthy' value, and in this case whatever of the 3 variables is defined & is not an empty string.